# Strict comparison behaves different in similar PHP version

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 8 application running on a production server with PHP 8.1.3, while the development server is running PHP 8.1.20.

Recently, I noticed that in an edit form, select options are losing their original state. My comparison condition is as follows:

```
@foreach ($areas as $area)
    <option value="{{ $area->id }}" {{ $area->id === $product->area_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $area->title }}</option>
@endforeach
```

After running some tests, I realized that the development server works as intended, but the production server doesn't.

Both servers are running Linux and using pretty similar PHP versions. When I dumped phpinfo(), I got the following:

**Development Server**

```
PHP Version: 8.1.20
Server API: LiteSpeed V8.0.1 CloudLinux 1.3
Zend Multibyte Support: provided by mbstring
Default Charset: UTF-8
```

**Production Server**

```
PHP Version: 8.1.3
LiteSpeed V8.0 CloudLinux 1.3
Zend Multibyte Support: provided by mbstring
Default Charset: UTF-8
```

To make the select work as expected, I had to use equality comparison (==) instead of identity (===).

Should I consider this as a result of different PHP versions, or should I investigate further to find differences in server configurations?"

This is my product table definition in both servers

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `intro` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `code` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `keywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `tags` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `published` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code_uniqu` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: What kind of values are in both variables and in both servers?

Comment: And similar, perhaps a bit of context where they stem from.

Comment: Just to note, `8.1.20 !== 8.1.2` `8.1.2 < 8.1.3` while `8.1.20 > 8.1.3`

Comment: I would more assume the id is an integer in one environment and a string in another can you check with dd() on product an area

Comment: @hakre Sorry for mistyping, correct dev server version is 8.1.20

Comment: What do `var_dump($area->id)` and `var_dump($product->area_id)` show the types to be?

Comment: There is very little chance that this is a result of the difference in PHP versions, as they're both the same minor version. The issue likely has to do with how the `$area` and `$product` objects get hydrated.

Comment: I've added product table definition for clarification. Both area->id and product->area_id are defined as BIGINT(20).

Comment: you still did not answer the question about var_dump or dd the models

Comment: _"Both area->id and product->area_id are defined as BIGINT(20)"_ This is not true. The database field type is unrelated to the PHP variable type. IIRC, the MySQL driver returns all values as strings. (Not sure if Laravel/Eloquent overrides that.)

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Depends on mysql driver and configuration. _native_ (mysqlnd) means PHP types. Also no clue for Laraveloquent default config regarding that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have a suspicion `$area->id` is automatically being cast to a numeric value by Laravel, but `$product->area_id` is not, yeah.

Comment: @ceejayoz your comment point in the right direction, because $area->id is returning an integer while $product->area_id is returning a string. Anyway, I can't understand why dev server accepts the equality comparator. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Farid You can likely fix that by using [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) to tell Laravel the type of that parameter.

Comment: If the value of area_id is larger than PHP_INT_MAX, it'll have no choice but to cast to string. Maybe your prod is 32 bit and your dev is 64?

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz, that's exactly what I did after I saw differences between both ids.